# Feedburner Subscribe box in wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, feed, feedburner

I want to display the same Subscribe box which is displayed on feedburner feeds: http://feeds.feedburner.com/michaelmartine/ymYs in my wordpress blog.

Is there any plugin of wordpress which will do this for me. I googled but didn't found such plugin, please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Feedsmith plugin is there.
See following
http://wpgpl.com/wordpress-plugins/feedburner-feedsmith-wordpress-plugin/